# Where are DataTable options defined?

Tags: datatables

My question: Is there any 1.10 documentation for features like aoColumns?

Background:  I am using DataTables 1.10.  To create a datatable with options enabling sorting on two of my three columns I found the following (which works):

```js
 dtable = $('#dtable').DataTable({
 "aoColumns" : [ {
    "sWidth" : "90%",
    "bSortable" : true,
    "class" : "t_col",
    "name" : 'trip'
 }, {
    "sWidth" : "5%",
    "bSortable" : true,
    "class" : "s_col",
    "name" : 'stat'
 }, {
    "sWidth" : "5%",
    "bSortable" : false,
    "class" : "d_col",
    "name" : 'del'
 }]
 });
```

I found this example online and (eventually) found documentation about aoColumns on the [DataTable legacy site](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns).  However, that legacy site clearly states, "This site contains the legacy documentation for DataTables v1.9 and earlier for reference only."  I can't find a 1.10 reference for this type of configuration anywhere.  Can someone point me to it if it exists?  (Same goes for [callback functions](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks))

Comment: The site layout is : **http://datatables.net** for 1.10.x documentation, **http://legacy.datatables.net** for 1.9.x and below documentation. The URL's are typically the same, eg **http://legacy.datatables.net/api** corresponds to **http://datatables.net/api**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [manual](http://datatables.net/manual/index) and [reference](http://datatables.net/reference/option/) on the front page. It seems that they have renamed a lot of the properties.

E.g. `aoColumns` and `aoColumnDefs` are now `columns` ([here](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns)) and `columnDefs` ([here](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs))

Callback are [here](http://datatables.net/reference/option/#Callbacks).

So your code in ver. 1.10 would be:

```
 dtable = $('#dtable').dataTable({
 "columns" : [ {
    "width" : "90%",
    "orderable" : true,
    className : "t_col",
    "name" : 'trip'
 }, {
    "width" : "5%",
    "orderable" : true,
    className : "s_col",
    "name" : 'stat'
 }, {
    "width" : "5%",
    "orderable" : false,
    className : "d_col",
    "name" : 'del'
 }]
 });
```

Comment: datatables 1.10.x options are backwards compatible with 1.9.x, so the suggestion above is just strict 1.10.x. OP's code works in any version.